# Passing action method names as arguments to facelets componenets

Tags: jsf, facelets, myfaces

I am calling a template and am passing in parameters like below:

```
<ui:include src="WEB-INF/Subviews/ProductEdit.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="items" value="#{produtList}"></ui:param>
    <ui:param name="itemToEdit" value="#{productToEdit}"></ui:param>
</ui:include>
```

and in the ProductEdit.xhtml, I have something like

```
<ui:repeat value="#{items}" var="item">
  <tr>
    ...
    ...
    <td style="text-align: center">
      <h:commandLink style="cssGenericColumn" action="#{productEditAction}">
         <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{itemToEdit}" value="#{item}"/>
      </h:commandLink>    
    </td>
  <tr>
</ui:repeat>
```

which works fine.

I now want to parameterize the #{productEditAction} in the ProductEdit.xhtml and so I did the following

```
<ui:include src="WEB-INF/Subviews/ProductEdit.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="items" value="#{produtList}"></ui:param>
    <ui:param name="itemToEdit" value="#{productToEdit}"></ui:param>
    <ui:param name="itemEditAction" value="#{productEditAction}"></ui:param>
</ui:include>
```

in the first page and then in ProductEdit.xhtml I do

```
<ui:repeat value="#{items}" var="item">
  <tr>
    ...
    ...
    <td style="text-align: center">
      <h:commandLink style="cssGenericColumn" action="#{itemEditAction}">
         <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{itemToEdit}" value="#{item}"/>
      </h:commandLink>    
    </td>
  <tr>
</ui:repeat>
```

and this fails on the following error

```
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: /WEB-INF/Subviews/ProductEdit.xhtml @45,89 action="#{itemEditAction}": Identity 'itemEditAction' does not reference a MethodExpression instance, returned type: java.lang.String
at com.sun.facelets.el.LegacyMethodBinding.invoke(LegacyMethodBinding.java:    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:109)....
 ....
 ....
 ....
```

This however works if the action bound to the model object. So something like

```
 <h:commandLink style="cssGenericColumn" action="#{item.editAction}">
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Passing a method as a parameter should be done in this way:

```
itemBean="#{bean}"
itemEditAction="productEditAction"
```

and in your component you will put them togheter:

```
action="#{itemBean[itemEditAction]}"
```

Comment: Bless you sir! You saved me putting my fist through the monitor, or worse, having to redesign my application.

Comment: If there wasn't a method named "productEditAction" in the controller, it will give an error at runtime instead of compile time because we are passing method name as a string instead of passing method directly (kinda like javascript) right?

Comment: Wait, where does this itemEditAction parameter assignation take place? Neither ui:param nor ui:include have such parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the [ActionMapperTagHandler](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/realworld/html/Button.html) would work.