JSF 2.3 f:ajax execute doesn't work across forms in composite component
I'm working on a JSF 2.3 project where I have a composite component comp:example that includes an h:commandLink with an f:ajax call. This composite component has its own h:form, but I want the f:ajax to execute and render components in a different form parentForm on the main page.
This is what the minimized code looks like
<h:form id="parentForm">
    <h:panelGroup id="someList">
        <!-- Content that should be executed -->
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
<comp:example id="example"
    renderTarget=":parentForm:someList"
    executeTarget=":parentForm:someList"
    customAction="#{myBean.someAction}" />

<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="renderTarget" />
    <composite:attribute name="executeTarget" />
    <composite:attribute name="customAction" />
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <h:form id="compForm">
        <h:commandLink rendered="#{not empty cc.attrs.customAction}">
            <f:ajax listener="#{cc.attrs.customAction}" render="#{cc.attrs.renderTarget}" execute="#{cc.attrs.executeTarget}" />
        </h:commandLink>
    </h:form>
</composite:implementation>

Problem:

The f:ajax correctly renders the target someList (#{cc.attrs.renderTarget}).
The execute attribute (#{cc.attrs.executeTarget}) doesn't work.

What I’ve Tried:

Using execute=":parentForm:someList" and variations like :parentForm, parentForm, @all etc.
Forcing form submission via custom JavaScript with jsf.ajax.request.
Adding immediate="true" to the h:commandLink.
Verifying there are no validation errors or FacesContext issues.

What am i missing?

Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5659405/passing-action-method-names-as-arguments-to-facelets-componenets
